# What's the proper way of adding a json subDataSource in Jasper Reports?

Tags: jasper-reports, jackson, ireport

I have this json DS:

```
{  
   "customername":"home",
   "workSiteRows":[  
      {  
         "invoiceRows":[  
            {  
               "candidateName":"name1",
               "units":"13:00"
            },
            {  
               "candidateName":"name2",
               "units":"18:30"
            }
         ],
         "workSiteName":"wsname1"
      },
      {  
         "invoiceRows":[  
            {  
               "candidateName":"name1",
               "units":"13:00"
            },
            {  
               "candidateName":"name2",
               "units":"18:30"
            }
         ],
         "workSiteName":"wsname2"
      }
   ]
}
```

In my .jrxml file I have defined a subreport and I'm trying to create a subDataSource to pass to this subreport.

```
<subreport isUsingCache="false">
   <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="555" height="30" uuid="b2d96c34-ad5d-4eb2-b218-43aad4e09282" />
   <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("workSiteRows")]]></dataSourceExpression>
   <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DIR} + "\\invoice_ws_row.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

I keep getting the following exception:
Error filling print...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode
```

I tried using the answer from question http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/956036/caused-javalangclassnotfoundexception-orgcodehausjacksonjsonnode-exception-ireport

But it does not work.
The problem is that currently jackson core is under the repo `"com.fasterxml.jackson.core"`

while iReport keeps asking for `"org.codehaus.jackson.core"`.

Tried looking for older versions of jackson core that are under org.codehaus and to add them to the iReport classpath but it still does not work.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you dont need to cast the expression.
Try: `<![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.subDataSource("workSiteRows")]]>`

This works just fine in my case.
In your case the subDataSource is an array, maybe you could also give it a try and use an object.

Comment: It works. thanks. ***facepalm***, btw, have you ever used other alternatives to Jasper Reports ?

Comment: You are welcome. I only know Jasper Reports, its free and the best available solution, but there are still plenty facepalm moments when using it :)

Comment: I am using JasperSoft Studio 6.2.1 and it is not possible to use the  `subDataSource` method without casting to `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource`